# Backbone.js is it ok to call a method on a view in the add handler of a collection?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, decoupling

I have a collection in backbone... in the initialize method I'm doing this.... I want to rerender a view when this collection has an item added to it.

```
initialize: function (models, options) {

        this.bind('add', function () {
            NS.discussionView.reRender();
        });
    }
```

This solution works perfectly however mycoworker says I'm totally going against what backbone was designed to do.  Is there a better approach to do this or is this an ok practice?  The questions a bit subjective, really I want to know how I should correctly be doing something like this.  Thanks for any feedback or advice.

Responding to the answer...
Well the object model is deeper. The discussionView has a discussionModel, which has a topics property which is a backbone collection of topic models. Each topic has a replies collection of reply models. When a reply is added to a topic, I need to render the discussionview again. How can I set that chain up correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply reverse the dependency: view might and should depend on model, but not the other way around. This way a single model might be used by several views (simple, detailed, etc.) and you might add views without modifying the model.

```
model.bind('add', function () {
    this.render();
});
```

Also prefer `render()` method name to follow Backbone.js naming convention.

Comment: Well the object model is deeper. The discussionView has a discussionModel, which has a topics property which is a backbone collection of topic models. Each topic has a replies collection of reply models.  When a reply is added to a topic, I need to render the discussionview again.  How can I set that chain up correctly?

Comment: this worked out well.  When I create the first level child views, I provide the each instance with a parentView property. The I bind the reply collection of each topic add handler and call this.parentView.render(). Works like a charm. Thanks!